# Custom field on ContentVersion returning 'NULL' in SOQL even value is assigned into the custom field

Tags: contentversion

I created a custom field lookup of "Account" on "ContentVersion" object, and I wrote a trigger on ContentVersion that will assign "Account" field with a specific Account.
Trigger is like this:-

```
Trigger assignAccount on ContentVersion(before insert){
          for(ContentVersion cv: Trigger.New){
                  cv.Account__c = '001i000000b7KxT';
         }
}
```

When I open the uploaded document then it show that "Shared with" 2 members one is the "Owner" and second one is the "Account", but the problem is that when I try SOQL and try to get the value of "Account__c" custom field then its giving me null fir "Account__c" field.

Comment: Can you provide the SOQL you are using to query the Account field?

Comment: List<ContentVersion> versions = [SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,Account__c FROM ContentVersion];

Comment: does the querying user have FLS permission to view the field?

Comment: How to set FLS for custom fields on ContentVersion object, when we create custom field then it does not give option to give permission and I think System Administrator have all permission on custom field and the "Salesforce CRM Content User" checkbox is also checked. Is there any other way to give FLS?

Comment: @ImranQureshi Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: How to give FLS to content version fields? example VersionData